# reflect change made by object affectation to scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I try to cancel changes made to a ng-repeat item by re-affecting a copy of it that I made just before editing it, the original object is affected but nothing change in the view. It's just plain weird, and I haven't figure out why!

http://jsfiddle.net/leseulsteve/a16j16mk/8/

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <ul ng-repeat="item in list">
    <li ng-click="edit(item)">{{item.description}}</li>
  </ul>
  {{originalDescription}}
</div>
```

--

```
function MyCtrl($scope, $timeout) {    
  $scope.list = [{
    description: 'I love bacon'
  }, {
    description: "J'aime le bacon"
  }];

  $scope.edit = function (item) {
    var originalItem = angular.copy(item);
    item.description = 'aaa';    /// update the view

    $timeout(function () {
        item = originalItem;   // doesn't update the view :((
        $scope.originalDescription = item.description;  // Show the original description.
    }, 1000);
  }
}
```

Comment: `item` is a local variable

Comment: it's been passed by the view, so I guess it's still the same variable?

Comment: The view calls your function with a reference to an item. This reference is put into a variable that you named `item` in the function. Note that the line that says `item.description` works. This is because the variable still references the original object. But if you change the variable's contents, the reference goes away, and instead you put something else there. The referenced object is still the same, you changed the variable that pointed to it.